# T-SQL - Is this possible (solve)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem to solve with any language I'm familiar with. I use SQL therefore was wondering if there is any help I could get for the following issue:

The following word:

```
CAPRICORN
```

Substitutes:

```
A = @
I = !
O = 0 (zero)
```

I must find all the combinations of the spelling Capricorn with and without the substitutes

Could anyone point me in the right direction of what to use or even a solution?

Kind Regards

Comment: This is not an operation best performed in SQL.  It is possible, but not simple.  Also, this sounds a lot like password hacking, so you might want to explain in the question why you want to do this.

Comment: It is password hacking - but on our own system for educational purposes. Yes, but unfortunately the only language I can use myself is SQL

Answer (score 13):

This is cartesian product or CROSS JOIN in SQL.

```
select cast('C' as varchar(50)) + a +'PR' +i + 'C' + o + 'RN'
from (values ('A'), ('@'))  t1(a)
cross join (values ('I'), ('!')) t2(i)     
cross join (values ('O'), ('0')) t3(o)
```

Comment: This is a good creative solution. My mind was thinking recursive sql, but clearly I missed the more simple answer. Nice!

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much

Comment: `Concat('C',a,'PR',i,'C',o,'RN')` is slightly nicer syntax perhaps (if the OP is on a recent version)

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
LIKE 'C[A@]PR[I!]C[O0]RN'
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to generate records with all possible combinations, not query all existing records with all possible combinations.